# ¿por que ciclo for se detiene antes de cumplir la condicion de un if?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning

Tengo el siguiente código en Python para realizar algunas iteracciones y encontrar el valor de ajuste usando el gradiente, pero este se detiene antes. Este es el código:

```
x=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
y=[5,7,9,14,18,22]
theta0=0
theta1=1
alpha=0.001
hx=0
hx2=0
ajuste=0
vuelta=0
#interacciones
for i in range(1,50000):
    temporaltheta0=theta0-alpha*(1/6)*(
    ((theta0+theta1*x[0])-y[0])+
    ((theta0+theta1*x[1])-y[1])+
    ((theta0+theta1*x[2])-y[2])+
    ((theta0+theta1*x[3])-y[3])+
    ((theta0+theta1*x[4])-y[4])+
    ((theta0+theta1*x[5])-y[5])
    )
    temporaltheta1=theta1-alpha*(1/6)*(
    ((theta0+theta1*x[0])-y[0])*x[0]+
    ((theta0+theta1*x[1])-y[1])*x[1]+
    ((theta0+theta1*x[2])-y[2])*x[2]+
    ((theta0+theta1*x[3])-y[3])*x[3]+
    ((theta0+theta1*x[4])-y[4])*x[4]+
    ((theta0+theta1*x[5])-y[5])*x[5]
    )

    #calculando ajuste
    hx=0
    for j in range(0,6):
       hx=hx+((theta0+(theta1*x[j]))-y[j])**2   
    ajuste=abs(hx-hx2)
    ajuste=round(ajuste,3)
    if ajuste>0.001:
       pass
    else:
       break
    print("la diferencia entre estos es: "+str(ajuste))
    hx2=hx
    print("valor de ajuste es: "+str(hx))

    theta0=temporaltheta0
    theta1=temporaltheta1
    vuelta=vuelta+1
print("theta0:"+str(theta0))
print("theta0:"+str(theta1))         
print("Se detuvo en la vuelta: "+str(vuelta))
```

El problema es que yo detengo el ciclo con un **break** pero este se detiene antes aunque el valor de ajuste sea mayor a 0.001, o sea que entra al if aunque no se cumpla la condición.

Comment: No sé si has identsdo bien el código, pero en este caso el `if` esta fiera de la condición y en caso este adentro tu ciclo `for` solo iterará 7 veces una vez cumplido esas 7 veces se termina

Comment: a si perdon no habia visto bien la indentacion pero ya lo corregi

Comment: Tu código ejecuta correctamente: termina cuando `ajuste <= 0.001`. Sin embargo, al terminar, haces `print("valor de ajuste es: "+str(hx))`  ... hay una discrepancia entre el mensaje y el valor.

Comment: cual seria? perdon

Answer (score 0):

No se si copiaste bien el código pero creo que está mal la sangrías. Si quieres que el if se ejecute dentro tienes que tener la sangría del for. Sería así:

```
hx=0
for j in range(0,6):
   hx=hx+((theta0+(theta1*x[j]))-y[j])**2   
   ajuste=abs(hx-hx2)
   ajuste=round(ajuste,3)
   if ajuste>0.001:
      pass
   else:
      break
```

Y luego si quieres meter lo de abajo en el for tiene que mantener la sangría de lo que hay dentro